# Using values in one associative array to test against values in another associative array

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, associative-array

I need help, tried for days without successs, new to PHP so please forgive me, I have an associative Array below returned from a database table grading system, what I want to achieve is try "scores" from another associative array, iterate through the grading system until I find a score that falls between values in a row in the grading system then return the letter grade and remarks, see below what have tried, am exhausted, any help would be very appreciated.
code I have tried

```
while ($row = $grade->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data = $row;
        var_export($data);
    } //fetches the grading system whose array is seen below

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $scores = $row;
    var_export($scores);
}// fetches scores of students in test
foreach($data as $key=> $grading) {
    foreach($scores as $key =>$values){


    if($values["marks"]>=$grading["grade_min"] && $values["marks"]<=$grading["grade_max"])
    print_r($values["marks"]);
    print_r($grading["grade"]);
    print_r($grading["remarks"]);
}
} Am trying to iterate each scores against the grading system but not successful, please help.
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [grade_min] => 1
            [grade_max] => 39
            [grade] => E
            [remarks] => Fail
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [grade_min] => 40
            [grade_max] => 49
            [grade] => D
            [remarks] => Pass
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [grade_min] => 50
            [grade_max] => 59
            [grade] => C
            [remarks] => Credit
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [grade_min] => 60
            [grade_max] => 69
            [grade] => B
            [remarks] => Good
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [grade_min] => 70
            [grade_max] => 79
            [grade] => A
            [remarks] => Very Good
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [grade_min] => 80
            [grade_max] => 100
            [grade] => A+
            [remarks] => Excellent
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [grade_min] => 1
            [grade_max] => 39
            [grade] => E
            [remarks] => Fail
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [grade_min] => 40
            [grade_max] => 49
            [grade] => D
            [remarks] => Pass
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [grade_min] => 50
            [grade_max] => 59
            [grade] => C
            [remarks] => Credit
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [grade_min] => 60
            [grade_max] => 69
            [grade] => B
            [remarks] => Good
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [grade_min] => 70
            [grade_max] => 79
            [grade] => A
            [remarks] => Very Good
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [grade_min] => 80
            [grade_max] => 100
            [grade] => A+
            [remarks] => Excellent
        )

)
```

Scores Array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 35
    [1] => 48
    [2] => 57
    [3] => 78
    [4] => 75
    [5] => 89
)
```

I want to iterate these scores array against the grading system array and return only the "grade" and "remarks" that matched where the scores is between "grade_min" and "grade_max"

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Could you [var_export()](https://www.php.net/var_export) your arrays and post it here so we don't have to re-type them to fiddle around with it?

Comment: @Triby, I have edited my question to show one of my unsuccessful attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to iterate over scores and then iterate grading to find the one that score belongs to.

Additionally, your if has no curly braces, so it will execute only the first sentence after it.

```
// fetches the grading system whose array is seen below
while ($row = $grade->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data = $row;
    // var_export($data); // No need to se this anymore
}

// fetches scores of students in test
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $scores = $row;
    // var_export($scores); // No need to see this anymore
}

// Iterate scores first (I don't know if you need the index or not)
foreach($scores as $scoreIndex => $score) {
    // Search grading for this score (Index not needed here, just values)
    foreach($data as $grading) {
        if($score['marks'] >= $grading['grade_min'] && $score['marks'] <= $grading['grade_max']) {
            // Score is inside this grading
            // Echo, print or assign what you need here

            // Then exit the loop for grading
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Based on your output for `$scores`, that array is just a single value, no associative array, so the loop should be:

```
// Iterate scores first (I don't know if you need the index or not)
foreach($scores as $scoreIndex => $score) {
    // Search grading for this score (Index not needed here, just values)
    foreach($data as $grading) {
        // $score is an integer, not an array
        if($score >= $grading['grade_min'] && $score <= $grading['grade_max']) {
            // Score is inside this grading
            // Echo here what you need

            // Then exit the loop for grading
            break;
        }
    }
}
```